# How can I get actual email address as a string from python email object

Tags: python, regex, email

I have created an email object using python's imaplib:

```
import email
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

>>> f = email_message ['From']
>>> f
'"bob smith" <bob5@xxxxx.org>'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\$<[^$]*>\$', f)
[]
```

I want to grab the actual email but the above is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: What does "Not working" mean?

Comment: My regex above yields an empty set "[]". I'm showing my interactive python code -Bill

Comment: re.findall("<(.*?)>",f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what all the dollar signs are for, but they are not necessary.  What you want to get is conveniently placed inside angle brackets.  So, all you need to do is capture stuff contained in them.

This can be done with [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

```
>>> from re import search
>>> f = '"bob smith" <bob5@xxxxx.org>'
>>> search('<(.*?)>$', f)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0213A520>
>>> search('<(.*?)>$', f).group(1)
'bob5@xxxxx.org'
>>>
```

Below is a breakdown of the Regex pattern:

```
<      # <
(.*?)  # Capture group for zero or more characters
>      # >
$      # End of string
```

Comment: @user61629 - `group(1)` is the text captured by `(.*?)`.  Here is a reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group